# Rescale an image on a log scale

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, imagemagick

I'm trying to rescale a map based on a log scale (so the first inch is about a mile, the second inch is two miles, the third is four miles, etc.). To complicate things, I would like this to be radial, starting from a point in the center. (Basically, I'm trying to show detail close to the center while covering a larger area in less detail with a smooth transition between them.)

I should note that I plan on starting with a very large image and scaling down.

Comment: @Scott I've Googled around, which came up with a whole lot of bupkis, so I haven't tried anything as yet. I don't know where to even start this in Photoshop or any other tool, and I would have to find and learn some image-manipulation library to write a program to do this (which is still my Plan B).

Comment: ImageMagick's "-implode" option (with a negative argument like "-.5" to explode instead).  In theory it should work but the results didn't look too good when I tried it with a satellite image of my home.  e.g., "convert satellite.png -implode -.5 exploded.png"

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @IronEagle No, I was never able to get the scaling function to return anything reasonable.